# Native App faster than HTML5

Tags: android, ios, html, native

I've always thought that an HTML5 application should have no weakness when compared to a native app, but according to the new facebook app that came out today, the speed improvements came when they switched to native iOS code instead of a web app.

> That includes a faster opening of the app itself, smoother and faster
>   scrolling, and photos that are said to load "instantly" -- changes
>   that are largely due to a switch from the old HTML5 code to iOS'
>   native programming language.

Can anyone vouch for these speed improvements? Is native development that much faster?

**Facebook for iOS goes native, waves goodbye to HTML 5**
http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/23/3262782/facebook-for-ios-native-app

Comment: When it's an HTML5 app, the program has to run on a Javascript engine, which will be slower than native code. Also, the Facebook app's executables will definitely be smaller than a Javascript engine and Webkit, so the app will load faster.

Comment: Wait, what? Facebook wasn't a native iOS app before? I AM APPALLED.

Comment: this might be a better question for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 7):

I found a link inside of the Link you posted that has a section on the page why it is faster

[Under the hood: Rebuilding facebook for IOS](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-ios/10151036091753920)

the section is named **(Re-)Building for speed**

> . One way we have achieved this is by re-balancing where we perform
>   certain tasks. For example, in iOS, the main thread drives the UI and
>   handles touch events, so the more work we do on the main thread, the
>   slower the app feels. Instead, we take care to perform computationally
>   expensive tasks in the background. This means all our networking
>   activity, JSON parsing, NSManagedObject creation, and saving to disk
>   never touches the main thread

Comment: this should probably be a comment

Comment: this is an off topic question and this is one of the better answers. it shouldn't be a comment.  it is much to long to be a comment, and it has too much information to be worked into a comment, it is an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's much faster. HTML5 Apps are written in Javascript and interpreted by the browser's JavaScript engine, whilst native apps run in native machine code (iOS) or at least as compiled byte code (Android). Also, native apps have much more possibilities to access the system they are running on (sensors like GPS, camera, file system, ...) through the APIs provided by the OS, whilst HTML5 apps are bound to the HTML5 API which is a small subset.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine there some some things native apps can do which HTML5 apps can't regarding memory deallocation and GPU rendering.